# Regex to match the following patterns

Tags: python, regex

I have the to match the following patterns.

```
RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TagTransAttempted:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(61);TagTransFailed:ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(42);TagTransApplied:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(19);
```

I have regex as follows in python.

```
for ele in re.findall("[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\(\d+\)",str(feed)):
    print ele
```

But this does not match JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE .

How do I specify more than one words separated by '_' and can contain digits?

Comment: Replace `[A-Z]` with `[A-Z\d]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the below regex.

```
[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+\(\d+\)
```

`+` repeats the previous token one or more times. `[A-Z\d]+` matches one or more uppercase letters or digits.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/wH1nK1/3)

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TextTransApplied:RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18), RENAME_IMAGE(7), MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26), (1), JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19), EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1), RENAME_CSS(3), (1), IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7), RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2);TagTransAttempted:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(61);TagTransFailed:ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(42);TagTransApplied:(8), ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(19);"
>>> for i in re.findall(r'[A-Z]+(?:_[A-Z\d]+)+\(\d+\)', s):
...     print(i)
RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18)
RENAME_IMAGE(7)
MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26)
JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19)
EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1)
RENAME_CSS(3)
IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7)
RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2)
RENAME_JAVASCRIPT(18)
RENAME_IMAGE(7)
MINIFY_JAVASCRIPT(26)
JAVASCRIPT_HTML5_CACHE(19)
EMBED_JAVASCRIPT(1)
RENAME_CSS(3)
IMAGE_COMPRESSION(7)
RESPONSIVE_IMAGES(6)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(2)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(61)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(42)
ASYNC_JAVASCRIPT(19)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+\(\d+\)|[^,]+(?<=\s)J+[^)]+\)`